# Jenkins Artifactory Plugin - 3.10.4 failing to deploy artifacts with below error(which is working good with 3.10.0)

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

The deploy maven artifacts is failing with Jenkins Artifactory Plugin - Version 3.10.4(which is working good with 3.10.0) Please suggest for any solution.

````
11:15:51  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/lang/String;
11:15:51    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.deployArtifacts(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:37)
11:15:51    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deploy(BuildDeploymentHelper.java:88)
11:15:51    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded(BuildInfoRecorder.java:169)
11:15:51    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:64)
11:15:51    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
11:15:51    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:137)
11:15:51    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
11:15:51    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
11:15:51    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
11:15:51    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
11:15:51    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
11:15:51    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
11:15:51    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
11:15:51    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
11:15:51    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
11:15:51    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
11:15:51    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
11:15:51    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
11:15:51    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
11:15:51    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
11:15:51  Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/lang/String;
11:15:51    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
11:15:51    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
11:15:51    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.deployArtifacts(ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:35)
11:15:51    ... 19 more
11:15:51  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/lang/String;

11:15:51  [main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded() listener has failed: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/lang/String; -> [Help 1]
11:15:51  org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded() listener has failed: ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins Artifactory Plugin 3.0.4 is using [IOUtils.toString(InputStream, Charset)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.charset.Charset-), which presented in Apache IOUtils 2.3, April 2012.

For some reason, the Maven resolver chose Apache IOUtils below 2.3, which is very old. This may occur due to another Jenkins plugin that utilizes this version.

I created https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/pull/450 to handle this issue by using [IOUtils.toString(InputStream, String)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-) which is presented in 2.1.

As a workaround, for now, you can use the Jenkins Artifactory plugin 3.10.0.

Comment: You can track this issue and download a snapshot with the fix here: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-1442